# Fail to store output of linux program to a file

Tags: c, linux, shell, printf

I have a simple program (which uses threads) called `./mpace` that uses `printf()` in the thread function. When I ran it from the terminal, the output is printed as it should, but when I type:

```
**./mpace > text**
```

the file created is empty.
The funny thing is that yesterday it worked perfectly. I typed:

```
echo "test" > text
```

to check if there is a serious problem with this function, but it worked. 
So, what could be the reason my program unexpectedly started failing to write to file?

Please note I'd prefer not to use `fprintf()` from my code, since time consumption is essential.

---

Thanks a lot, the problem was solved simply by using fflush(stdout). I thought printing in a new line would flush the channel, but as paxdiablo explains in a comment here it doesn't:

[Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

You are right that one should offer as much as information as he can,but I thought  that sharing 100 lines of code for a single printf() would be a drag for you to read. I see this was a bad decision, since not using fflush and the fact that the program is being terminated by a signal both contributed to the problem and should have been made known.

Comment: Sharing relevant parts of your code will allow others to answer you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a buffering issue. `stdout` is line buffered only if it goes to a character device. To check if this is the problem, call `fflush(stdout)` manually after every `printf` call. Make sure that the output buffer of `stdout` is flushed correctly before your program terminates.

Comment: Unless the process is terminated by a signal or calling `_exit()`, the buffers are guaranteed to be flushed.

Comment: @EOF This function is called `_Exit()` in ISO 9899:2011. `_exit()` is a POSIX function from `unistd.h` defined to be equal in behaviour to `_Exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be because you are using **>** instead of **>>** and probably somehow your code (**which by the way, you didn't share it**) contains a newline (blank) and delete the old one. let me show you an Example.

Let say we have the following file called **file1.txt** which contains the following information:

> ```
> Michael  
> Jimmy
> Dolores
> ```

And I wont to extract the name Jimmy and redirect the output to another file called **file2.txt**

```
cat file1.txt | grep "Jimmy" > file2.txt
```

Now the file2.txt contains:

> Jimmy

Now lets run this command 3-4 times and check that file again:

```
cat file2.txt
```

Output:

> Jimmy

Why is this ? it should be:

> ```
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> ```

Well becouse i used **>** instead of **>>.** Now let's try again:

```
michi@michi-laptop:~$ cat file1.txt | grep "Jimmy" >> file2.txt 
michi@michi-laptop:~$ cat file1.txt | grep "Jimmy" >> file2.txt 
michi@michi-laptop:~$ cat file1.txt | grep "Jimmy" >> file2.txt 
michi@michi-laptop:~$ cat file1.txt | grep "Jimmy" >> file2.txt
```

Output:

> ```
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> ```

This could be one of the reasons.

EDIT:
I come with another short example, let us modify Jimmy with Timmy:

> ```
> Michael
> Timmy
> Dolores
> ```

Remember the file2.txt looks like this:

> ```
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> Jimmy
> ```

Now if you run:

```
cat file1.txt | grep "Jimmy" > file2.txt
```

I just got myself with an empty file because of **>** instead of **>>** , there is no Jimmy in **file1.txt**.